# How do I unnest a nested df and use the coumn name as part of the new column name?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I realize my title is probably a little confusing.  I have some JSON that is a little confusing to `unnest`.  I am trying to use the tidyverse.

Sample Data

```
df <- structure(list(long_abbr = c("Team11", "BBS"), short_name = c("Ac ", 
                                                                    "BK"), division = c("", ""), name = c("AC Slaters Muscles", "Broken Bats"
                                                                    ), abbr = c("T1", "T1"), owners = list(structure(list(commissioner = 0L, 
                                                                                                                          name = "Chris Liss", id = "300144F8-79F4-11EA-8F25-9AE405472731"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
                                                                                                           structure(list(commissioner = 1L, name = "Mark Ortin", id = "90849EF6-7427-11EA-95AA-4EEEAC7F8CD2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
                     id = c("1", "2"), logged_in_team = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_
                     )), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
                 )



# Unnest Owners Information
df <- df %>% 
  unnest(owners)
```

I get the following error since I have duplicate columns that use `name`.

```
Error: Column names `name` and `id` must not be duplicated.
```

Is there an easy way to unnest the columns with a naming convention that takes the prefix `owners` (or in my case, I'd want it to take whatever the name of the column that hold the nested `df` is) before the nested columns.  I.E.  `owners.commissioner`, `owners.name`, `owners.id`.  I'd also be interested in solutions that use camel case, and an underscore.  I.E. `ownersName`, or `owners_name`.

Answer (score 0):

set the argument `names_sep`:

```r
df <- structure(
  list(long_abbr = c("Team11", "BBS"), 
       short_name = c("Ac ", "BK"), 
       division = c("", ""), 
       name = c("AC Slaters Muscles", "Broken Bats"), 
       abbr = c("T1", "T1"), 
       owners = list(
         structure(list(commissioner = 0L, name = "Chris Liss", 
                        id = "300144F8-79F4-11EA-8F25-9AE405472731"), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
         structure(list(commissioner = 1L, name = "Mark Ortin", 
                        id = "90849EF6-7427-11EA-95AA-4EEEAC7F8CD2"), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
       id = c("1", "2"), 
       logged_in_team = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), 
  row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"
)

tidyr::unnest(df, owners, names_sep = "_")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 10
#>   long_abbr short_name division name  abbr  owners_commissi… owners_name
#>   <chr>     <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <chr>            <int> <chr>      
#> 1 Team11    "Ac "      ""       AC S… T1                   0 Chris Liss 
#> 2 BBS       "BK"       ""       Brok… T1                   1 Mark Ortin 
#> # … with 3 more variables: owners_id <chr>, id <chr>, logged_in_team <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes!  Is there any way to rename using loweCamel?

Comment: try convert the first letter of column name to upper case, and then set `names_sep = ""`